Trying to configure OpenVPN on a server, but encounter an error
To install Open-VPN on a server I followed these commands:
Install Ansible and Git:
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip git rsync ansible

Clone this repository:
git clone https://github.com/d3vilh/openvpn-aws

Then enter the repository directory:
cd openvpn-aws

Install requirements:
ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml --force

If you see ansible-galaxy: command not found, you have to relogin and then try again.
Make copies of the configuration files and modify them for your environment:
yes | cp -p example.config.yml config.yml

Run the following command to add the docker group if it doesn't exist and add user to the docker group:
sudo groupadd docker

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

Relogin now to apply group changes.
`Double check that ansible_user is correct for inventory.yml. Nee`d to run installtion on the remote server - follow the recomendations in config file.

`nano inventory.yml`, save the file - `Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+X` to exit.

Run installation playbook:
sudo ansible-playbook main.yml

After following all instructions for installing OpenVPN, I encountered  this error.

> fatal: [openvpn-aws]: FAILED! => {"reason": "couldn't resolve
> module/action 'community.docker.docker_compose_v2'. This often
> indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module
> path.\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/home/ubuntu/openvpn-aws/tasks/openvpn_ubuntu.yml': line 37, column
> 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
> problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# to the `docker`
> group, so this task may fail.\n- name: Ensure OpenVPN is running
> (Ubuntu).\n  ^ here\n"}


I've been trying different solutions to install OpenVPN, but I haven't been successful. I've searched online for instructions on using Docker files and changing parameters in the openvpn_ubuntu.yml file, but they haven't been helpful. Do you have any ideas on how I can properly install OpenVPN?
This is the line 37 to 40 of this file mentioned in the error:
> 37 - name: Ensure OpenVPN is running (Ubuntu).                        
> 38   community.docker.docker_compose_v2:                              
> 39     project_src: "{{/home/ubuntu/openvpn-aws}}"                    
> 40     state: present


What is line 37 in /home/ubuntu/openvpn-aws/tasks/openvpn_ubuntu.yml?

@Organic Marble It is line 37 in "openvpn_ubuntu.yml" file

Yes, but what is the content of that line?

Thanks for the edit. This appears to be the key error message: couldn't resolve
module/action 'community.docker.docker_compose_v2'. This often
indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module
path I know nothing about docker so I can't help with resolution.

It seems you are following the steps explained in https://github.com/d3vilh/openvpn-aws , however you have not done step 7.
You are supposed to edit inventory.yml and do so according to the comments at the end of the file:

Comment out "Section One" parameters and uncomment "Section Two" to run on remote OpenVPN-AWS environment.
Double check the ansible_user and ansible_host.

